# How to search blogs on blog.com?

Tags: search, blog

When I log into blog.com, I can not find a search function to look for blogs on blog.com that are related to a specific topic. In fact, I can hardly find other blogs except of mine. The only way to find other blogs is using " visit random blog" menu item, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Head to Google.com and search using `site:*.blog.com keywords to search for`.

Comment: I would like to know if blog.com itself has some functionality for searching.

Answer (score 1):

When I go to www.blogs.com, I do not see any options to log in.    But I do see a nice search function near the top right corner:

[image: screenshot from www.blogs.com]

Did you actually means blogs.com, or perhaps another tool like Blogger.com?

Comment: blogs.com now redirect to typepad.com. The last doesn't seem to me to have a blog search box.